# Query on Impala tarball

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, impala

I want to install impala from a tarball manually i do not want to use apt-get command and manager. Where can i get a tarball and steps to install the same? 
I want other Components also which are there in CDH4 package but not available as tarball on cloudera site.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: What's wrong with apt-get or Cloudera Manager ?

Comment: nothing wrong but due to some reasons i have to install it using tarball